What are BFE, BFC & BGC when it comes to UK's Census Boundaries?
I am looking to download UK's Census Boundaries from the ONS' Open Geography Portal.
All the Census level boundaries that I can find, have a suffix such as BFE, BFC & BGC.
See for example: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?q=BDY_OA%20DEC_2021&sort=Title%7Ctitle%7Casc
What do these suffixes mean? Where can I find the official definitions of these ?

The homepage of the website explains it:

Which spatial dataset format should I use?
A brief explanation:
Full Extent (BFE) – Full resolution boundaries go to the Extent of the
Realm (Low Water Mark) and are the most detailed of the boundaries.
Full Clipped (BFC) – Full resolution boundaries that are clipped to
the coastline (Mean High Water mark).
Generalised Clipped (BGC) - Generalised to 20m and clipped to the
coastline (Mean High Water mark) and more generalised than the BFE
boundaries.
Super Generalised Clipped (BSC) (200m) – Generalised to 200m and
clipped to the coastline (Mean High Water mark).
Ultra Generalised Clipped (BUC) (500m) – Generalised to 500m and
clipped to the coastline (Mean High Water mark).
Grid, Extent (BGE) - Grid formed of equally sized cells which extend
beyond the coastline.
Generalised, Grid (BGG) - Generalised 50m grid squares.

